# CSV Input in gensim LDA via corpora.csvcorpus

Tags: python-3.x, csv, gensim, lda, corpus

I wanna use the LDA in gensim for topic modeling over a few thousand documents.
Therefore I´m using a csv-File as Input in the format of a term-document-matrix.

Currently it occurs an error when running the following code:

```
from gensim import corpora

import_path ="TDM.csv"

dictionary = corpora.csvcorpus(import_path, labels='true')
```

The error is the following:

```
dictionary = corpora.csvcorpus(import_path, labels='true')

AttributeError: module 'gensim.corpora' has no attribute 'csvcorpus'
```

Am I using the module correctly and if so, where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have run the same code a few more times and now the error changed to:

dict = corpora.csvcorpus(import_path, labels='true')

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What is the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also bugged me for quite awhile.
It looks like csvcorpus is actually in the experimental stage as you can see in their github issue, https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1583

I would recommend going by the old fashioned way of using the csv package to read your csv file instead.

Cheers.

Comment: Ok, thanks
I found a work around with the module csv already.